# How do I say in one word "going further"?

Tags: word-request

I am actually writing a computer program. I think that practically everyone knows how programs work at the very high level: they have conditions and if conditions are met then a program **goes further**.

Now what I would like to know is: how can I say in one word "to go further", or even "condition to met to go further".

Comment: I would prefer to use "execution flow" instead of "program". Program is an artifact, for example .exe file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When its conditions are met, your program *[**proceeds**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceed)*:

> 2a : to continue after a pause or interruption
>   b : to go on in an orderly regulated way
>
> 4: to move along a course : advance
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proceed)*</sub>

And those conditions can be referred to as ***[prerequisites](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite)*** (or *preconditions*, if you prefer):

> something that is necessary to an end or to the carrying out of a function
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite)*</sub>

M-W goes on to explain that a prerequisite "can be anything that must be accomplished or acquired before something else can be done."

Comment: How bizarre! My first thought when I read this question was that [*the program **continues***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+program+proceeds%2Cthe+program+continues&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20program%20proceeds%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20program%20continues%3B%2Cc0) sounds like a much more likely verb. But when I created that linked NGram to double-check/prove the point, although it showed something like a 3:1 preference in support of my choice, I thought it might be ***even stronger*** for software in particular...

Comment: ...so I tried [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer+program+proceeds%2Ccomputer+program+continues&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20program%20proceeds%3B%2Cc0) specifically comparing *the **computer** program proceeds / continues*. But according to that one, ***continues*** is so uncommon it doesn't chart at all. Perhaps the old Cobol ***Procedure** Division* has greater "reach" here than the oft-maligned ***Continue*** reserved word in more modern languages like C++.

Comment: @Fumble it could be because “continue” is a keyword with a specific meaning in many programming languages that its use is avoided for a more general sense.

Comment: Hellion, thank you! I knew the "proceed" word but completely forgot it. @FumbleFingers, ColleenV is correct, a "continue" word is a keyword with a completely different meaning - to continue to a next iteration of a loop.

Comment: But we can and do say that **execution continues**. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22program+execution+continues%22&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjptOnbmO3cAhUjqlkKHcVfDhQQ_AUIECgB&biw=1822&bih=886